# Access to a pop-up in selenium

Tags: selenium

I do have the following code to click a Google button that open a pop-up and then it selects the second Item. It worked fine but now is failing, I guess that due to ID name changed. I do not remember how I Inpectioned the pop-up ID since it does not appears in the "Inpection" Chrome Window.

```
numOpiniones.click()
self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//button[@data-value='Ordenar']").click()
        sleep(random.uniform(1, 1.5))
        self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//li[@role='menuitemradio' and @data-index='1']").click()
```

"menuitemradio" does not exists anymore but I can not see that element in the inspector panel when is created/displayed.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dY2nd.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following css path

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#hovercard > #action-menu > [data-index="1"]')
```